# Performance of Infinispan Distributed Streams

Tags: mapreduce, java-8, infinispan

Infinispan 8.2.x (latest version) introduces distributed streams (of java 8) and depreciates the MapReduce implementation [1]. That rises the question on performance enhancements.

Are there any benchmarks run to test the performance benefits? According to Infinispan team, there have been internal benchmarks showing the performance benefit of Infinispan's distributed streams [2]. However, I could not find the results or pointers to detailed discussions yet.

How does the Infinispan distributed streams achieve higher performance than Infinispan MapReduce? Does it take advantage of the SIMD (Single input multiple data) operations?

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/distexec/mapreduce/MapReduceTask.html

[2] https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268188?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder, to be honest we have been a bit lax on blogging about the performance increase for this.  I hope that we can get one out in the near future.  I can however show you an image from the graph that was generated in the benchmark test that was ran.  The y axis is MB/s and the x axis is # of unique words (in all tests it was doing a simple word count).  The blog should show more details.

[image: Chart]

These tests were all ran with radargun [2] btw.  The test driver for Map Reduce can be found at [3] and distributed streams with [4].

But from the chart Map/Reduce is close in performance (~15-30% less than distributed streams), but once the intermediate results grew in size Map/Reduce fell off and ran out of memory.  Spark in this case also had twice as much memory as distributed streams (so I was fighting those results a little).  But this should be detailed more once we have a blog post.

But in regards to why distributed streams is faster, the biggest thing is that we utilize Java 8 Streams under the hood which provide good cpu cache hits and low overhead of context switching using a fork join pool.  Map/Reduce has a lot of these optimizations but was missing some :)

Also don't forget Distributed Streams is fully rehash aware and you don't have to worry about duplicate/lost entries when a node enter/leaves like you do with Map/Reduce.  You can also read more about Distributed Streams at [5].

[2] https://github.com/radargun/radargun

[3] https://github.com/radargun/radargun/blob/master/extensions/mapreduce/src/main/java/org/radargun/stages/mapreduce/MapReduceStage.java

[4] https://github.com/radargun/radargun/blob/master/extensions/cache/src/main/java/org/radargun/stages/stream/StreamStage.java

[5] http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#streams

Comment: Thanks for sharing some insights. The results will depend on the nature of the application/workload and the deployment environment. For example, see the similar simple tests I ran on Hazelcast's initial MapReduce implementation vs. Infinispan's 2 years ago - http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2014/05/mapreduce-implementations-hazelcast-vs.html 

I assume the MapReduce used here was the Infinispan implementation.

How does this scale? How many instances in this experiment? If so, will the results change/revert in a much larger or smaller scale?

Does it take advantage of the SIMD operations?

Comment: I too would love to see the blog post! That said, why is Spark faster as the word count increases (and oddly, it's much faster -- like 3x faster -- for just one entry, the 1e7 word count one)?

Comment: Unfortunately the person who performed the test didn't finish the blog post. However I have posted a couple more posts about improvements for distributed streams [1] [2]. The first one is about iteration, which helps the spark test case and the second one improves performance for things like word count substantially.

[1] https://blog.infinispan.org/2018/02/distributed-iteration-improvements.html
[2] https://blog.infinispan.org/2018/10/segmented-data-containers-distributed.html

Comment: In regards to why spark was faster, I am pretty sure it was because the spark test case had double the memory than the distributed stream one. Each Infinispan embedded node had 32GB JVM heap, irrespective of the test. However the spark test also had 32 GB heap for each spark worker node. Therefore the spark node didn't have to share data and computation results in the same JVM, where as distributed streams did and would hit GC pauses.